# REST API search query for all pages and document

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, sharepoint-rest-api, sharepoint-search

I'm trying to find a REST API query which shows all HTML, CSS, js ect. all type of pages and documents. I'm trying to get exact same results as SharePoint default search.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following query url, this will give you all the records associated with document content type.

```
https://yourtenant.sharepoint.com/_api/search/query?querytemplate='IsDocument:true'
```

You can also query something like below, where you are trying to find document with specific term

```
https://yourtenant.sharepoint.com/_api/search/query?querytext='search_data'&querytemplate='{searchterms} IsDocument:true'
```

By default SP REST API display 10 records. Add row limits to query to include as many result items you desire.

You can also follow [MSDN documentation to learn more on SP Search](https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/general-development/sharepoint-search-rest-api-overview).

Answer (score 0):

You can use below REST API

**To get all Documents/ Pages from site :**

```
/_api/search/query?querytext='IsDocument:True'
```

**To get specific pages/files like CSS,JS,HTML etc :**

```
/_api/search/query?querytext='FileExtension:<extension>'
```

**Example:**

```
/_api/search/query?querytext='FileExtension:html'
```